# Which two numbers are most frequently found together?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysql table that records user id's depending which picture  they selected (pic1,pic2 or pic3). I want to be able to print out which two user id's are most frequently found in the **same row** regardless of which pic they selected.

In the table below the answer would be 4 and 6 as they are most commonly found in the same row. I can't figure out how to build a query that would do this and I think the only way might be with a multi-query but I figure out how to build them. Can anyone help me?

```
     pic1    |    pic2   |   pic3   
-------------------------------------
       4            null       6
       6             4        null
       4             9        null
       6            null       4
```

I suppose the first part of my query would look like this but then what?: Note $userid is the logged in user.

```
"SELECT pic1, pic2, pic3 FROM mytable where pic1='$userid' OR pic2='$userid' OR pic3='$userid'";
```

Comment: are there more fields in your table? primary key?

Comment: in your sample every row has two different users and a null, is that true for all your data?

Comment: "Which two numbers are most frequently found together?" - Number ones and number twos in the toilet!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if every row has only two different users you can use this query to get all ordered pairs of users and how many times they appear together:

```
SELECT mn, mx, COUNT(*)
  FROM (select if(pic1 is null, least(pic2, pic3), least(pic1, coalesce(pic2, pic3))) mn,
               if(pic1 is null, greatest(pic2, pic3), greatest(pic1, coalesce(pic2, pic3))) mx
          from t) x
 GROUP BY mn, mx
 ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Note that least and greatest functions return NULL if a value is NULL, that's why if and coalesce  functions are necessary.

To get only the pairs of users that have max count the query will be longer:

```
SELECT mn, mx, count(*) cnt
  FROM (select if(pic1 is null, least(pic2, pic3), least(pic1, coalesce(pic2, pic3))) mn,
               if(pic1 is null, greatest(pic2, pic3), greatest(pic1, coalesce(pic2, pic3))) mx
          from t) x
 GROUP BY mn, mx
HAVING count(*) = (select max(cnt) from (SELECT mn, mx, count(*) cnt
                                           FROM (select if(pic1 is null, least(pic2, pic3), least(pic1, coalesce(pic2, pic3))) mn,
   if(pic1 is null, greatest(pic2, pic3), greatest(pic1, coalesce(pic2, pic3))) mx
                     from t) x
                                          GROUP BY mn, mx) y);
```

see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2bcb/14/0)

Comment: I wanted to use LEAST(pic1, pic2, pic3) and GREATEST(pic1, pic2, pic3) to return only an ordered pair of ids, but these functions return NULL when any of the values is NULL. This way works, but is less readable.

Comment: to filter by a particular userid you'd have to add what you suggested in both inner subqueries (note that they are identical).

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the correct result:

```
SELECT LEAST(p1, p2) AS p1, GREATEST(p1,p2) AS p2
FROM (
  SELECT pic1 AS p1, pic2 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic1 IS NOT NULL AND pic2 IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pic1 AS p1, pic3 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic1 IS NOT NULL AND pic3 IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pic2 AS p1, pic3 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic3 IS NOT NULL AND pic2 IS NOT NULL
) s
GROUP BY LEAST(p1, p2), GREATEST(p1,p2)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes great!. This worked too. I like this solution the best as I find it easier to understand. Thank you all.

Comment: If I wanted to filter these results and only show the results that have a chosen id in it how would this be done? For example  where could I put this  ? `where pic1='$userid' OR pic2='$userid' OR pic3='$userid'`

Comment: @JulianJ you can add a `WHERE p1='$userid' or p2='$userid'` before the group by (slower but easier to understand) or you can filter every single subquery `FROM mytable1 WHERE (pic1 IS NOT NULL and pic2 IS NOT NULL) AND (pic1='$userid' OR pic2='$userid')`